# Establishing automated Serial port connection with Bluetooth device in Windows

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, msdn

Am trying to establish automated serial connection with a medical bluetooth device.

For ex .
the device is paired with a comport number 20 .The problem in this device is once the device is turned off ,it disconnects the bluetooth connection resulting the comport in some inaccessible state.(ie. when i try to open the create file handle returns 0x79 -ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT).

So i tried polling for the comport connection as shown below in main thread ,

```
{
......

    do
    {

        hSerial = CreateFileA(pcomport,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            0,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            IO_ATTRIBUTE,
            0);

        if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            result = GetLastError();
            if (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND == result)
            {
                //serial port does not exist. Inform user and exit for now...
                printf("spc [OpenSerialPort]:unable to detect COM port: %s\n", pcomport);
                return hSerial;
            }
            //some other error occurred. Inform user.
            printf("spc [OpenSerialPort]:unknown error 0x%08x at %s\n", result, pcomport);
            CloseHandle(hSerial);
            //return hSerial;
        }
    } while (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

....
}
```

This seems to work fine .But the problem am facing is when i try to open some other device comport where bluetooth connection is maintained ,it fails .(may be because of polling with a win api ).

I couldnt find any method in msdn to detect the connection is established.

How can i  automate this scenario .ie ,whenever the device is on ,the serial port should be opened and should continue in next cycle.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?